# Error de Implementación de LaravelVue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify

Consulta. Alguién ha implementado laravue? 
https://doc.laravue.dev/

Luego de Instalarlo y salir todo bien cuando intento ingresar a las secciones de manejo de Usuarios, Roles, Permisos,etc, me arroja un error Request failed with status code 500, es decir, cuando intenta comunicarse con la DB. Los cambios de conexión los hice en el archivo .env

La verdad no puedo encontrar el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor consulta el log de errores de Laravel, verifica si se han guardado mensajes y agrégalos a tu pregunta

Comment: Acabo de Resolverlo, era que no tenia permisos la carpeta storage para guardar los logs. Ud sabe como se pone una pregunta como resuelta?

Comment: Pública todo el procedimiento de forma detallada paso q paso abajo en la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 0):

logré resolver el problema planteado. Al menos en mi caso, lo que me mostraba la herramienta de desarrollador del navegador Mozilla no permitía darme cuenta en donde estaba el error, o que era lo que sucedía. Solamente me tiraba un error 500. Lo que hice fue instalar la herramienta de debug de laravel.

En esta URL esta todo el procedimiento para instalarla.

https://styde.net/instalar-barra-de-debug-en-laravel/

Allí sí, pude darme cuenta que el error era que no podía acceder a la carpeta Storage para guardar los logs de laravel. Tan simple como eso jajaja

Entonces lo que hice fue en una consola escribir el comando de linux que realiza esta acción que es el siguiente

```
sudo chmod 777 storage
```

y listo problema resuelta